# How to perform logical operations between logical qubits in a $[\![8,3,2]\!]$ quantum code?

Tags: quantum-gate, error-correction, fault-tolerance

I have a small question on codes like $[\![8,3,2]\!]$, which encodes physical qubits to multiple logical qubits.  How do we perform logical operations in between these logical qubits?

Of course, if I have two of such code blocks I have transversal $\text{CNOT}$ etc.

But say I just have these 3 logical qubits, can I still perform logical operations between logical qubit 1 and logical qubit 2 efficiently?

Comment: Does [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.08663.pdf) answer your question?